# java - jdbc performance

Tags: java, performance, oracle, jdbc

I need one help from you guys regarding JDBC performance optimization. One of our pojo is using jdbc to connect to a oracle database and retrieve the records. Basically the records are email addresses basing upon which emails will be sent to the users. The problem here is the performance. This process happens every weekend and the records are very huge in number, around 100k.

The performance is very slow and it worries us a lot. Only 1000 records seem to be fetched from the database every 1 hour, which means that it will take 100 hours for this process to complete (which is very bad). Please help me on this.

The database server and the java process are in two different remote servers. We have used `rs_email.setFetchSize(1000);` hoping that it would make any difference but no change at all.
The same query executed on server takes 0.35 seconds to complete. Any quick suggestion would of great help to us.

Thanks,
Aamer.

Comment: When you say "remote server" do you actually mean "servers that are far apart" (in terms of network infrastructure) or do you simply mean that they are two separate servers (in the same data center)? That kind of performance should *not* happen anyway. Do you execute only a single query?

Comment: Please show us the queries that are being performed here and maybe some pseudocode of the process.  Right now we are guessing at the problems.

Comment: Are you sure that the fetch is the slow point?  The fact that you are fetching only 1000 rows per hour raises a red flag (for me) that the stuff processing the rows is the choke point.

Comment: Another idea; Are you connecting to the database to fetch each row?  In general, that is a bad idea.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with retrieving the mailaddresses from the database, and not with - for example - sending the email? In the past I have seen SMTP services taking several seconds to send a single message because of various security checks (origin, destination, blacklists, reverse DNS checks that failed or were slow etc). In your example a single message takes 3.6 seconds to process. I would sooner try to blame the sending of mail, than the database.

Answer (score 1):

First look at your queries. Analyze them. See if the SQL could be made more efficient (ie, ask the database for what you want, not for what you don't want -- makes a big difference). Also check to see if there are indexes on any fields in your where and join clauses. Indexes make a big difference. But it can't be just any indexes. They have to be good indexes (ie, that the fields that make up the index provide enough uniqueness for the database to retrieve things appropriately). Work with your DBA on this. Look for either high run time against the db or check for queries with high CPU usage (even if the queries run sub-second). These are the thing that can kill your database.

Also from a code perspective, check to see if you are opening and closing your connections or if you are re-using them. Can make a big difference too.

It would help to post your code, queries, table layouts, and any indexes you have.

Answer (score 0):

Use [log4jdbc](http://www.google.by/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=log4jdbc&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http://log4jdbc.sourceforge.net/&ei=EtEWT_e0OY-j-gbsydWTBA&usg=AFQjCNHpUdBeU0I-I4EnZ0tmfjPz6eeY3A) to get the real sql for fetching single record. Then check speed and plan for that sql. You may need a proper index or even db defragmentation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the Oracle driver, but I do know that the MySQL driver supports two different results retrieval methods: "stream" and "wait until you've got it all".

The streaming method lets you start process the results the moment you've got the first row returned from the query, whereas the other method retrieves the entire resultset before you can start work on it. In cases where you deal with huge recordsets, this often leads to memory exceptions, or slow performance because java hit the "memory roof" and the garbage collector can't throw away "used" records like it can in the streaming mode.

The streaming mode doesn't let you navigate/scroll the resultset the way the "normal"/"wait until you've got it all" mode...

Anyway, not sure if this is of any help but it might be worth checking out.

Comment: By the way...make sure the connection uses compression. In cases where you're not retrieving results from the same physical server, compression can often give a fair performance boost.

Comment: there's tonnes of other things such as clustering indexes, using materialised query tables, partitioning data but I'd for the low hanging fruit first.

Answer (score 0):

My answer to your question, in summary is:
1. Check network
2. Check SQL
3. Check Java code.

It sounds very slow. First thing to check would be to see if you have a slow network.  You can do this pretty quickly by just pinging the database server.  Or run the database server on the same machine as your  JVMM.  If it is not the network, get an explain plan for your SQL and ensure you are not doing table scans when you don't need to be.   If it is not the network or the SQL, then it's time to check your Java code. Are you doing anything like blocking when you shouldn't be?